# Get friends read articles with Facebook JS API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'd like to know how to fetch articles that friends have read from a Facebook app. I use the following query to get articles that I have read:

```
    /me/news.reads
```

But i want all the articles that friends have read, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is not an apt solution but you can do is loop through facebook id's of your friends and for each friend's Id get all the news read as `/$friend_id/news:reads`
I dont think there is any direct api function to get action performed by friends.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
FB.api('/me/friends', { 'fields' : 'name,news.reads.limit(10)' }, function (data) {
    // if(!data || data.error) { }
    // console.log(data);
});
```

You can omit the limit if you like, or add more fields. Of course this would also work as a GET request to: `http://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=name,news.reads.limit(10)&access_token=XXXX`